# Who are these neighbors?

Tags: riddle

Five people live in the same neighborhood:

- Neighbor A is the most judgmental.
- Neighbor B is the most helpful.
- Neighbor C is the most hateful.
- Neighbor D is the most loving.
- Neighbor E is the most trustworthy.

Who are they?

Comment: Is this going to be another "22 intrinsically with a possible range between 22 and 96"? :-) *<sees answers>* Ooh, nice!

Comment: Five **people** live in the same neighbourhood?

Comment: @LamarLatrell I think you could justify the choice of that word as a form of personification, I think it would be difficult to write the question differently and it makes people think more abstractly.

Comment: @Ambo100, "Five individuals are neighbours:" ? But I agree, then the 'who/what are they?' might be more of a giveaway ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are the

> 5 fingers.

---

Neighbor A is the most judgmental.

> Thumb, [Thumbs Up or Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumb_signal) means approval of someone.

---

Neighbor B is the most helpful.

> Index finger. [It helps in making children learn](https://babybigstep.com/All-about-toddlers/baby-pointing-finger-to-communicate) [as](https://www.livescience.com/18844-finger-pointing-kids.html) [per](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.701.1921&rep=rep1&type=pdf) [Developmental Psychology](https://goldin-meadow-lab.uchicago.edu/sites/goldin-meadow-lab.uchicago.edu/files/uploads/PDFs/2014_Cartmill%20et%20al.pdf)

Neighbor C is the most hateful.

> [The middle finger](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Middle%20Finger)!

Neighbor D is the most loving.

> The fourth finger [for the marriage ring](http://www.businessinsider.com/wedding-ring-on-fourth-finger-why-2017-4?IR=T)

---

Neighbor E is the most trustworthy.

> The little finger for [The Pinky Promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinky_swear).

---

Adding source links in a few seconds.

Comment: "Ugh, not another ___ riddle. Ehhh... okay, I guess this one's kinda cute." +1 after all.

Answer (score 8):

These are

> fingers of one's hand

As,

Neighbor A is the most judgmental.

> the thumb

Neighbor B is the most helpful.

> index finger for pointing/identifying

Neighbor C is the most hateful.

> offensive notation by middle finger alone

Neighbor D is the most loving.

> rings of love are worn on this finger, usually

Neighbor E is the most trustworthy.

> one hold's one's father's hand as a child (little finger)

**Another alternate answer:**

These are

> the first FIVE days of a working week! As,

Neighbor A is the most judgmental.

> Monday usually decides (as most believe in) how the remaining of week goes!

Neighbor B is the most helpful.

> Tuesday, after completing Monday would be accommodating our chores and in that way it is helpful

Neighbor C is the most hateful.

> being in the middle of a week, one has to attend all ___ meetings and calls resulting in a hateful feedback for Wednesday (also less chances for availing leaves :-( )

Neighbor D is the most loving.

> Feeling of approaching weekend in a day comforts one and hence becomes lovely one

Neighbor E is the most trustworthy.

> TGIF (sure shot for a weekend and hence most trustworthy!)

Comment: Ha ha. +1 for the alternative answer. It's funny and sad because it's true. ha ha .

Comment: *** is the most trustworthy... Right up until that verrry last moment ;-)